# How to consolidate 3 SQL-queries in one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three separate queries and need to combine it in one to prepare data for a chart. So the common parameter for all 3 datasets is the date.
Please help me to do it.

1)

```
SELECT COUNT(id) Registrations, regdate
FROM wpu_users
WHERE regdate >= '2020-01-09'
GROUP BY regdate;
```

2)

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(total)) as amount, DATE(datetime) as date
FROM wp_payments
WHERE site_id=4 AND status=1
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

3)

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cnt)) as Matrix, DATE(datetime) as date
   FROM wp_payments
   WHERE site_id=4
     AND status=1
     AND currency='USD'
     AND description LIKE '% + %'
     AND datetime IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY date
```

The result should be a table with columns:

```
Registrations 
amount 
Matrix 
date
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the results that you want.

Comment: Ok, that has done

Comment: Its better to provide the schema and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement. try this

```
SELECT
    tab1.Registrations as  "Registrations",
    tab2.amount as "Amount",
    tab3.Matrix as "Matrix",
    tab1.regdate as "Date"
FROM
    ( SELECT COUNT( id ) Registrations, regdate FROM wpu_users where regdate >= '2020-01-09' GROUP BY regdate ) tab1
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ROUND( SUM( total ) ) AS amount,
        DATE( datetime ) AS date 
    FROM
        wp_payments 
    WHERE
        site_id = 4 
        AND STATUS = 1 
    GROUP BY
        date 
    ) tab2 ON tab1.regdate = tab2.date
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ROUND( SUM( cnt ) ) AS Matrix,
        DATE( datetime ) AS date 
    FROM
        wp_payments 
    WHERE
        site_id = 4 
        AND STATUS = 1 
        AND currency = 'USD' 
        AND description LIKE '% + %' 
        AND datetime IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY
    date 
    ) tab3 ON tab1.regdate = tab3.date
```

Comment: Hm
It returns an error:
Error running query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>= '2020-01-09' GROUP BY regdate ) tab1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT ROUN' at line 7

Comment: next error: Error running query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2 ON tab1.regdate = tab2.date INNER JOIN ( SELECT ROUND( SUM( cn' at line 19

Comment: It was due to space between tab 2. It should be tab2